# the partial derivative of $f(x,y)=\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}), f_x (3,4)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I know the answer is $\dfrac{1}{8}(1 +\dfrac{3}{5} )$ but i do not understand where the 1 inside the bracket comes from, I know how to get the $\dfrac{1}{8}$ and $\dfrac{3}{5}$ can someone clarify?

Comment: Do you remember the chain rule?

Comment: never mind i understand..

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{d}{dx}\log x=\frac1x\;\;,\;\;\frac d{dx}\left(x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)=1+\frac x{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$

so applying the chain rule:

$$\frac d{dx}\log\left(x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)=\frac1{x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\left(1+\frac x{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right)$$

Now substitute $\;(x,y)\to (3,4)\;$ ....

Answer (score 0):

Hint 0: Using the definition of partial derivative we have

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(3,4):=\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(3+t,4)-f(3,4)}{t}=
\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{\ln\left( t+3+\sqrt{t^2+6t+25}            \right)-\ln 8 }{t};$$

all you need to finish the proof is the Taylor expansion of

$$\ln\left( t+3+\sqrt{t^2+6t+25}            \right) (*) $$

at $t=0$, i.e.

$$\ln\left( t+3+\sqrt{t^2+6t+25}            \right)=\ln 8+ (...)t+O(t^2).$$

Hint 1: the expression $\frac{1}{8}(1+\frac{3}{5})$ you refer to is precisely the derivative of $(*)$ w.r.t. $t$ at $t=0$: it appears in the Taylor formula above.

Comment: A computer scientist, eh?

Comment: Uhmm...nope, why? :-)

Comment: Your first hint is *Hint 0* :)

Comment: :-) :-) :-) :-) (btw...4 is the minimum number of 1 unit spaced-with nose smiles that is accepted as a comment)

Comment: :-------------)

Comment: eheh, I forgot the Pinocchio smiley :-)

Comment: That's weird, I use it the most. :-------------)